# LinkedList implementation in Java with generics and enhanced for

Tags: java, generics, data-structures, iterator, iterable

I need you to review my implementation of a Singly Linked List (SLL) please. The implementation should use generics and be able to use the enhanced for.

The problem is that, when I do `for (Number n : list)` being `list` a `MyLinkedList<Integer>` or `MyLinkedList<Double>`, I get the error: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Number".

This is what I have. The parts I am not very certain about are the generics and the iterators.

Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class MyLinkedList<T> implements Iterable<Object>
{
    private Node head;

    public MyLinkedList ()
    {
        head = null;
    }

    public void add (Node n)
    {
        if (head == null)
        {
            head = n;
        }

        else
        {
            Node node = head;
            while (node.next != null) 
            {
                node = node.next;
            }
            node = n;
        }
    }

    public Iterator iterator() 
    {
        return new MyLinkedListIterator (head);
    }

    public int size () 
    {
        int ret = 0;
        MyLinkedListIterator it = new MyLinkedListIterator (head);
        while (it.hasNext ())
        {
            it.next();
            ret++;
        }

        return ret;
    }

    public Node getHead ()
    {
        return head;
    }
}

class MyLinkedListIterator<T> implements Iterator
{
    private Node node;

    public MyLinkedListIterator (Node h)
    {
        node = h;
    }

    public MyLinkedListIterator (MyLinkedList<T> l)
    {
        this(l.getHead ());
    }

    public boolean hasNext () 
    {
        if (node.next == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Object next () 
    {
        return node.next;
    }

    public void remove () 
    {

    }   
}
```

Comment: Why not just use the built in java.util.LinkedList? The only reason that comes to mind is if this is a homework assignment, or you're trying to gain an understanding of how linked lists and generics work. (If this is homework, you should tag it with 'homework')

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- You should have `Iterable<T>` instead of `Iterable<Object>`.
- `add(Node)` doesn't actually add an object to the list.
- `MyLinkedListIterator<T>` should implement `Iterator<T>`.
- `MyLinkedListIterator.hasNext()` will throw a `NullPointerException` if the list is empty.
- `MyLinkedListIterator.next()` doesn't move to the next item in the list.

Answer (score 2):

You should return an `Iterator<T>` from the `iterator` method and you should also extend `Iterable<T>` instead of `Iterable<Object>`.

Besides, your `MyLinkedListIterator<T>` should implement `Iterator<T>`. Then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use `<E>`

```
public class Node<E>{
 E data;
 Node<E> next;
}

public class SinglyLinkedList<E> {
  
 Node<E> start;
 int size;
 .......
}
```

Look [here](https://tech.bragboy.com/2010/01/linked-lists.html) for a comprehensive implementation

Comment: The link above seems spamy

Answer (score 1):

On top of what the others have said, you probably shouldn't be exposing `Node` in your public methods - nodes should be a purely internal aspect of the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the point: MyLinkedListIterator.next() doesn't move to the next item in the list.

the next method should be something along these lines to get it working:

```
public T next() {
    if(isFirstNode) {
        isFirstNode = false;
        return node.data;
    }
    node = node.next;
    return node.data;
}
```